Оптимизация хранения в Redis
Всех приветствую
Пишу телеграм бота с использованием редис для хранения состояний пользователя. При сохранении некоторых состояний - данными этих состояний могут являться текстовые сообщения большого объема, динамически полученные во время диалога пользователя с ботом. В редис мои данные хранятся в виде пары ключ:значение, однако в роли значения выступает полученное сообщение в Unicode, где каждая русская буква кодируется в виде последовательности символов, например \u0412.
Подскажите, как мне оптимизировать хранение данных для подобных ситуаций, чтобы у меня запись занимала меньше места, возможно где то в коде фреймворка нужно заменить тип кодировки... Всю голову сломал
Код фреймворка aiogram.fsm.storage.redis:
import json
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager
from typing import Any, AsyncGenerator, Callable, Dict, Optional, cast

from redis.asyncio.client import Redis
from redis.asyncio.connection import ConnectionPool
from redis.asyncio.lock import Lock
from redis.typing import ExpiryT

from aiogram.fsm.state import State
from aiogram.fsm.storage.base import (
    BaseEventIsolation,
    BaseStorage,
    DefaultKeyBuilder,
    KeyBuilder,
    StateType,
    StorageKey,
)

DEFAULT_REDIS_LOCK_KWARGS = {"timeout": 60}
_JsonLoads = Callable[..., Any]
_JsonDumps = Callable[..., str]


class RedisStorage(BaseStorage):
    """
    Redis storage required :code:`redis` package installed (:code:`pip install redis`)
    """

    def __init__(
        self,
        redis: Redis,
        key_builder: Optional[KeyBuilder] = None,
        state_ttl: Optional[ExpiryT] = None,
        data_ttl: Optional[ExpiryT] = None,
        json_loads: _JsonLoads = json.loads,
        json_dumps: _JsonDumps = json.dumps,
    ) -> None:
        """
        :param redis: Instance of Redis connection
        :param key_builder: builder that helps to convert contextual key to string
        :param state_ttl: TTL for state records
        :param data_ttl: TTL for data records
        """
        if key_builder is None:
            key_builder = DefaultKeyBuilder()
        self.redis = redis
        self.key_builder = key_builder
        self.state_ttl = state_ttl
        self.data_ttl = data_ttl
        self.json_loads = json_loads
        self.json_dumps = json_dumps

    @classmethod
    def from_url(
        cls, url: str, connection_kwargs: Optional[Dict[str, Any]] = None, **kwargs: Any
    ) -> "RedisStorage":
        """
        Create an instance of :class:`RedisStorage` with specifying the connection string

        :param url: for example :code:`redis://user:password@host:port/db`
        :param connection_kwargs: see :code:`redis` docs
        :param kwargs: arguments to be passed to :class:`RedisStorage`
        :return: an instance of :class:`RedisStorage`
        """
        if connection_kwargs is None:
            connection_kwargs = {}
        pool = ConnectionPool.from_url(url, **connection_kwargs)
        redis = Redis(connection_pool=pool)
        return cls(redis=redis, **kwargs)

    def create_isolation(self, **kwargs: Any) -> "RedisEventIsolation":
        return RedisEventIsolation(redis=self.redis, key_builder=self.key_builder, **kwargs)

    async def close(self) -> None:
        await self.redis.aclose(close_connection_pool=True)

    async def set_state(
        self,
        key: StorageKey,
        state: StateType = None,
    ) -> None:
        redis_key = self.key_builder.build(key, "state")
        if state is None:
            await self.redis.delete(redis_key)
        else:
            await self.redis.set(
                redis_key,
                cast(str, state.state if isinstance(state, State) else state),
                ex=self.state_ttl,
            )

    async def get_state(
        self,
        key: StorageKey,
    ) -> Optional[str]:
        redis_key = self.key_builder.build(key, "state")
        value = await self.redis.get(redis_key)
        if isinstance(value, bytes):
            return value.decode("utf-8")
        return cast(Optional[str], value)

    async def set_data(
        self,
        key: StorageKey,
        data: Dict[str, Any],
    ) -> None:
        redis_key = self.key_builder.build(key, "data")
        if not data:
            await self.redis.delete(redis_key)
            return
        await self.redis.set(
            redis_key,
            self.json_dumps(data),
            ex=self.data_ttl,
        )

    async def get_data(
        self,
        key: StorageKey,
    ) -> Dict[str, Any]:
        redis_key = self.key_builder.build(key, "data")
        value = await self.redis.get(redis_key)
        if value is None:
            return {}
        if isinstance(value, bytes):
            value = value.decode("utf-8")
        return cast(Dict[str, Any], self.json_loads(value))


class RedisEventIsolation(BaseEventIsolation):
    def __init__(
        self,
        redis: Redis,
        key_builder: Optional[KeyBuilder] = None,
        lock_kwargs: Optional[Dict[str, Any]] = None,
    ) -> None:
        if key_builder is None:
            key_builder = DefaultKeyBuilder()
        if lock_kwargs is None:
            lock_kwargs = DEFAULT_REDIS_LOCK_KWARGS
        self.redis = redis
        self.key_builder = key_builder
        self.lock_kwargs = lock_kwargs

    @classmethod
    def from_url(
        cls,
        url: str,
        connection_kwargs: Optional[Dict[str, Any]] = None,
        **kwargs: Any,
    ) -> "RedisEventIsolation":
        if connection_kwargs is None:
            connection_kwargs = {}
        pool = ConnectionPool.from_url(url, **connection_kwargs)
        redis = Redis(connection_pool=pool)
        return cls(redis=redis, **kwargs)

    @asynccontextmanager
    async def lock(
        self,
        key: StorageKey,
    ) -> AsyncGenerator[None, None]:
        redis_key = self.key_builder.build(key, "lock")
        async with self.redis.lock(name=redis_key, **self.lock_kwargs, lock_class=Lock):
            yield None

    async def close(self) -> None:
        pass


Если говорить про количество байт на символ, то кириллические символы занимают по 2 байта что в utf-8, что в utf-16. Есть кодировки в которых кириллица занимает по одному байту, например CP1251. Теоретически, так можно в 2 раза сэкономить для русского текста (английские буквы там тоже по 1 байту).
Если тексты совсем большие, то можно попробовать алгоритмы сжатия. Их много разных и нужно будет повыбирать и подобрать баланс между памятью и скоростью.

В моем случае каждая русская буква кодируется 6-значной последовательностью по типу \u0412, в таком случае занимаемый объем получается в 6 раз больше ожидаемого. Не знаю как исправить данную проблему, буду благодарен за любую помощь!

Если речь об обычном юникоде, то \u0412 это не 6 символов, а просто номер символа юникода, который при кодировании в utf-8 или utf-16 преобразуется в 2 байта.
Если же там на самом хранится 6 символов \ u 0 4 1 2, то это не нормально и это надо переделать на один символ, соответствующий этому коду юникода.
